# Surround every word with double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have to write function in C# which will surround every word with double quotes. I want it to look like this:

```
"Its" "Suposed" "To" "Be" "Like" "This"
```

Here is the code I've come up with so far, but its not working:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] words = txtText.Text.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        string test = word.Replace(word, '"' + word + '"');

    }
    lblText.Text = words.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it depends to some degree on what you consider a 'word', but you can use a regular expression:

```
lblText.Text = Regex.Replace(lblText.Text, @"\w+", "\"$0\"")
```

This will match any sequence of one or more ['word' characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordCharacter) (which in the context of regular expressions includes letters, digits, and underscores) in the string, and wrap it with double quotes.

To wrap any sequence of [non-whitespace characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NonWhitespaceCharacter), you can use the `\S` instead of `\w`:

```
lblText.Text = Regex.Replace(lblText.Text, @"\S+", "\"$0\"")
```

Comment: This breaks when you have a space in a word like "hello world"!

Comment: @HoKy22 You have a very strange definition of the word "*word*".

Answer (score 3):

It isn't working because `Replace` does not change its argument. The variable `test`, which contains the desired value, is never used.

You could also do it using Linq as follows:

```
return String.Join(" ", txtTextText.Split(' ').Select( word => "\"" + word "\""));
```

Comment: `.Map` isn't a .NET function. I think you meant `.Select`. Also, as of .NET 4, you don't have to call `.ToArray`

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] words = txtText.Text.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        string test = word.Replace(word, '"' + word + '"');
    }
    lblText.Text = words.ToString();
}
```

To:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] words = txtText.Text.Split(' ');
    string test = String.Empty;
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        test += word.Replace(word, '"' + word + '"');
    }
    lblText.Text = test.ToString();
}
```

You were not doing anything with the `test` string. And the string was reset every loop iteration, it is appending now.

Answer (score 3):

to stick to the OPs approach:

```
string input ="It's going to be a fine day";
string[] words = input.Split(' ');
string result = String.Empty;
foreach (string word in words)
{
    result += String.Format("\"" + word + "\" ");
}
```

I added a space after the word.

so your code should look like this:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = String.Empty;
    string[] words = txtText.Text.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        test += String.Format("\"" + word + "\" ");
    }
    lblText.Text = test;
}
```

Comment: This was exactley what I was looking for. Works perfect also thanks!

Comment: The call to `String.Format` does nothing. 
        `test += "\"" + word + "\" ";` would be enough.

Comment: I'm a creature of habit. You're right of course. I'm using String.Format almost everytime to get kind of a visual wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Linq* here:

```
 lblText.Text = String.Join(" ", txtText.Text.Split(' ').Select(x => "\"" + x + "\""));
```

Comment: Thanks, much apricaited!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add single quotes to each word, try something like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
int i = 0;
yourStringArray.ToList().ForEach(x => list.Add(string.Format("'{0}'", yourStringArray[i++])));
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be enough

```
string txtText = "this is a string";
string[] words = txtText.Split(' ');
txtText =  @"""" + string.Join(@"""", words) + @"""";
```

output

```
 "this"is"a"string"
```

Comment: works, but not what i were looking for, but thanks, the problem is solved ;)!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            string input = "It's going to be a fine day";
            string[] words = input.Split(' ');
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                {
                    sb.Append("\"");
                    sb.Append(word);
                    sb.Append("\" ");
                }
            }
          lblText.Text = sb.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: Output: `"It's""going""to""be""a""fine""day"`